# Do Gogeta and Vegito have all the same techniques?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes, Vegito has shown to be capable of using the kaioken. But Vegito in the same story and others doesnt use it.

Do Gogeta and Vegito have all the same techniques?

Answer (score -1):

Gogeta and Vegeta are 2 different forms of fusion - One is formed by potara and other by fusion dance so they use same techniques.
Currently there is no official news of Dragon Ball Super but a rumour going of Super Season 2.
As for Heroes series it is fan-made going on as like GT series not made by the Dragon Ball Z or Super creator